# Is Voltdb supported by Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, voltdb

Can I use Voltdb with Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 4):

No, while VoltDB does have a Ruby Gem available http://rubyredtomatoes.com/2010/11/01/still-voltdb-and-ruby, http://rubygems.org/gems/voltrb and http://github.com/beljun/VoltRb it is not supported by Ruby on Rails.

In VoltDB your schema (tables and indexes) and access (SQL within Java Stored Procedures) must be defined in advance.